# How to plot in MATLAB the Frequency Response for a speaker

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency, frequency-analysis, speaker

I am trying to get the frequency response of a speaker by playing a 20Hz to 20KHz chirp through the speaker and comparing the speaker output sound file to the original input sound file.  This is what I have so far but the plot doesn't look like I expect. The Y-axis does not seem to be in dB. I may also be doing it completely wrong I'm not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!
[image: Frequency Response Plot Output]

```
[y,fs] = wavread('LogChirp.wav');
[x,fs] = wavread('bose sweep 2 feet.wav');
y = reshape([y;zeros(145824-144000,1)],145824,1);
ydft = fft(x)./fft(y);
% Assume y has even length
ydft = ydft(1:length(y)/2+1);
% create a frequency vector
freq = 0:fs/length(y):fs/2;
% plot magnitude
ydft1 = smooth(ydft,.1);
p = semilogx(freq,ydft1);
p = plot(freq,abs(ydft));
set(p, 'Color', 'blue', 'LineWidth', 1);
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('');
title('Frequency Response');
grid on;
%axis([20,20e3,-1,1]);
```

Comment: Have a look at `pwelch`, better for spectral estimation. Aside from that, what you can estimate this way is the combined frequency response of the speaker and the microphone you use to pick the sound up again. Unless you now the microphone's characteristics, there is no way to disentangle the two.

Comment: The `y` axis is probably in magnitude.  If you want to convert to dB, use `20*log10(abs(ydft))`.

Answer (score 0):

To have both X and Y axes in dB you can use the `loglog` function to plot the data.
Also consider that in your script you have two consecutive plot instructions

```
p = semilogx(freq,ydft1);
p = plot(freq,abs(ydft));
```

but not the instruction"`hold on`".

Without "`hold on`" only the last graph will be displayed.

Moreover the two plot instructions uses different type of scale (log the first, linera the second) MatLab does not "like" this and keeps the firt of them for all the plots.

Hope this helps.